# How do semaphores allowing negatives work?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I've read very conflicting sources online about whether a semaphore can have a non-zero value. It seems like in some implementations this signifies the number of waiting threads, but I can't seem to get this. If I'm understanding correctly, the count value says how many open "slots" there are. So first of all, I can't see how you can have negative slots if the semaphore blocks a wait call until count is positive. I also don't see how the number of waiting threads would have anything to do with the number of open slots. How do negative values of the counter variable work in these situations?

Please refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6heMm23ofFo&nohtml5=False) to see how he is explaining semaphores with negative values for example.

Comment: Can your provide an example or link where the semaphore count goes to zero, and how this is being handled?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see my edit.

Comment: It might be better to give an example in your actual question.  Links can move or even break over time.

Answer (score 0):

please quote the source or paste some code.

Semaphore are generally binary, meaning their value is either a 0 or 1.

1. What `count` are you referring to?

In general sense, `count` can be the number of waiting threads. I don't understand what slots you refer to.

2. Waiting threads generally enter a queue and go to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please see my edit for the source.